# Does increasing number of observations lead to the decreasing of Mean Square Error of consistent estimators?

Tags: logistic, maximum-likelihood, estimators, mse, consistency

I know that not all weakly consistent estimators exhibit MSE-consistency : https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/610835/397467.

Anyway, does increasing the sample size leads to a reduction in their mean squared error ?

Specifically, I am trying to find a formal mathematical argument to explain why models such as Logistic Regression (that are based on maximizing likelihood) gives better estimation of their coefficients when we train them on a large dataset. Maximum Likelihood Estimators are known to be consistent but I haven't found properties on their MSE.

Comment: pretty much for the same reason why CLT has a $.../n$ in the variance

Comment: yes i understand that for classical estimators as the empiric mean but in this case I don't get it. I think, in the described problem, it is more a convergence problem equivalent to "Convergence in probability implies a likely L^2 decrease"

Answer (score 2):

Let's see how far we can go with this, using a bit naive/informal reasoning:

Define $(\hat \theta_n - \theta)^2 \equiv \Delta_n$. Then

$${\rm consistency}: \Pr(|\hat \theta_n - \theta| < \epsilon') \to 1  \implies \Pr(|\hat \theta_n - \theta|^2 > \epsilon'^2) \to 0,$$

$$\implies \Pr(\Delta_n \geq \epsilon) \to 0. \tag{1}$$

Also,
$$MSE \equiv E(\hat \theta_n - \theta)^2 = E(\Delta_n). \tag{2}$$

For some $\epsilon >0$, decompose the expected value

$$E(\Delta_n) = E(\Delta_n \mid \Delta_n < \epsilon)\cdot\Pr(\Delta_n < \epsilon) + E(\Delta_n \mid \Delta_n \geq \epsilon)\cdot\Pr(\Delta_n \geq \epsilon).$$

We also have by basic properties of the expected value,
$$E(\Delta_n \mid \Delta_n < \epsilon) \leq \epsilon,$$

and since $\Pr$ is bounded by unity
$$MSE = E(\Delta_n) \leq \epsilon + E(\Delta_n \mid \Delta_n \geq \epsilon)\cdot\Pr(\Delta_n \geq \epsilon) \tag{3}$$

As sample size $n$ increases, we will eventually be able to choose smaller and smaller $\epsilon$. Also, we know from the consistency property that $\Pr(\Delta_n \geq \epsilon)$ will tend to zero. So the weak consistency property certainly pushes for the MSE to reduce in value.

More over, if $E(\Delta_n \mid \Delta_n \geq \epsilon)$ is bounded, the second term will certainly go to zero.

But, in the thread the OP links to, we see an example where in an analogous situation (with a mixture estimator), the corresponding part of the MSE *stabilizes* to a non-zero value.

In such a case also the MSE falls, although it does not reach zero. This and other such examples have certainly an artificial flavor, and their main purpose is to show why MSE-consistency is a stronger property.

But for most, if not all *practical* cases, we will see the MSE fall.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very delailed response ! However I don't understand why MSE should have certainly a decreasing value. I mean or $E(\Delta_n | \Delta_n > \epsilon )$  is bounded and then the estimator is MSE consistent or $E(\Delta_n | \Delta_n > \epsilon )$ diverge and then we cannot conclude anything on the decreasing of the MSE. I try to find something with successive decreasing values of epsilon but I don't succeed yet.

Comment: @whn The whole point is that to have a divergent $E(\Delta_n \mid \Delta_n \geq \epsilon)$, and in fact "so" divergent that it overcomes the plunge of $\Pr(\Delta_n \geq \epsilon)$ towards zero, is something that does not happen except in artificially constructed examples (caveat: all discussion here is subject to all these expected values existing of course). Think of what kind of distributions may $\Delta_n$ follow.